# Python prints out formula from excel cells but not value

Tags: python, excel

I am using these codes to work with my excel file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Wages.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode ="a")
wb = writer.book
ws2 = wb["Living Wages"]
```

Now i want to print out the value from a specific cell, for example:

```
print(ws2.cell(row=2, column= 2).value)
```

Problem: Python prints out "=N2/12" because thats the formula i used for the cell above but i want to print out the true value which is 2562.23

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Wages.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode ="a", data_only = False)
i added data_only = False but it print out this error:  FutureWarning: Use of **kwargs is deprecated, use engine_kwargs instead.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830171/10739252, it might help you.

Comment: @VladSiv i saw that page, thats how i came to the idea to use data_only. But it uses load_workbook. I stricly want to/have to use pd.ExcelWriter

Comment: @CaptainTrojan thank you! I am new to programming/python, what exactly is engine kwargs? i think understand the code from the page you showed me but i dont know how to use it for myself.